# Which telescope should I buy?

Tags: telescope, space

I'm wondering which telescope I should buy, by the way, I'm new to astronomy and if you know any others that are under $100, It'd be appreciated. You don't need to take the price difference into consideration when replying, thank you!

## 1 : http://www.dshop.com.au/buy/astronomical-telescope-675x-magnification/F90060M?gclid=CjwKCAjw-qbLBRB7EiwAftBCI7h_7lH3E9goJG4Top0N-OHaraxB0cM8IiZgfygRkHD8DZ1ThARCdRoCzA8QAvD_BwE

***Features***:

Maximum magnification: 675x

Large aperture offers clearly illuminated views

Stable construction provides solid support and control

Metal tripod with slow motion control rod

Strong performance in both high and low magnification

Easy sky focusing with finderscope

***Specifications***:

Aperture: 60mm (2.36inch)

Focal Length: 900mm.f/15

Finderscope:  5x24

Diagonal Prisms: 90degree

Slow Motion Control Rod For Easy Vertial Micro Adjustment

Height: 128cm

Eyepiece: SR4mm H12.5mm H20mm

3X Barlow Lens, 1.5X Erector

Telescopic Aluminum Tripod

## 2 : https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/617033-REG/Celestron_21035_Travel_Scope_2_7_70mm_Refractor.html

***Specifications***:

70mm Achromatic Refractor

400mm Focal Length, f/5.7 Focal Ratio

Anti-Reflection Fully Coated Optics

1.25" Rack-and-Pinion Focuser

Manual Alt-Azimuth Mount with Lock

10mm and 20mm Eyepieces, Erecting Prism

5x24 Finderscope

Aluminum Photo-Style Tripod

Backpack Holds OTA, Tripod, Accessories

Comment: Answers to this question will be almost entirely opinion based. There is no clear-cut way of saying which telescope will be better than the other. As such, this is not a good question for this site.

Comment: Definitely not the first. It's a toy and will be totally useless. Contact an astronomy club if you can and get some advice from them. You may be able to try some telescopes at a meeting, and someone may even have a telescope that they are willing to sell.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two, I would go with the Celestron - it's from a named and respected manufacturer with sensible specifications and relevant additional equipment. The eyepiece selection is thoughtful.

However, you pay the price because the Celestron's focal length at 400mm is much more limited. The best magnification you'll be able to get is 40x without a Barlow (good for the Moon but rather anaemic for the planets).

The other scope promises much higher magnifications but I worry that the manufacturer's name isn't stated, that there seems to be a number of redundant extra items and about the overall build quality.

Personally, I would consider the https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/485261-REG/Celestron_21061_AstroMaster_70_AZ_2_7_70mm_Refractor.html as an alternative, though it is a little more expensive.

Comment: what if I added this telescope, what would be better then : 

https://www.opticscentral.com.au/saxon-707az2-refractor-telescope.html?___SID=U#.WW56y9N940p